# Android NDK/JNI -- shared library incompatible with armelf_linux_eabi

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use Android NDK and JNI to call a C++ function from Kotlin in my Android Studio project.

Here's my Android project structure:

```
myproject/app/src/main  
│
└───java
│   │
│   └───com.example.myproject
│       │   MainActivity.kt
│   
└───cpp
|   │   native-lib.cpp
|   │   CMakeLists.txt
|   │
|   └───mylib
|       │   Number.hpp
|       |   Number.cpp
│   
└───jniLibs
    │   libmylib.so
```

Notice, I've already built this program into `libmylib.so`, and saved it to `src/main/jniLibs`. I want to use this built library, rather than `Number.cpp` directly.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project("myproject")
add_library(myproject SHARED native-lib.cpp)
add_library(MYLIB SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MYLIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION jniLibs/libmylib.so)
target_link_libraries(myproject MYLIB)
```

Yet I get this error when building:

```
C/C++: ld: error: jniLibs/libmylib.so is incompatible with armelf_linux_eabi
```

How can I get cmake to properly link the library to my project?

Comment: Your use of `${MYLIB}` looks weird. That's something you might use e.g. if you've used `find_library` which places the result in a variable. Have you tried just writing `target_link_libraries(myproject MYLIB)` instead?

Comment: Ah, now I get a different error, updated the question

Comment: Was libnavtoolkit.so also built with the Android SDK? Is it built for the same ABI that you're trying to build `myproject` for?

Comment: It was cross-built in a meson project using the Android NDK 23b linux-x86_64 compilers for aarch64-linux-android SDK 28

Comment: And which ABI(s) are you building `myproject` for?

Comment: I believe it would be arm64-v8a, since the target system is android, and the target cpu is aarch64

Comment: Ah, I think I have to add `abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'` to build.gradle

Comment: @Michael do you want to add an answer so I can accept it? The problem was as you implied: by default, Android Studio was trying to build `myproject` for [all the available ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa), but `libmylib.so` was only built for ABI `arm64-v8a`, so I had to specify this ABI in my `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker error suggests that you are building `myproject` for a different ABI than the one that `libmylib.so` was built for.

You can tell Gradle to only build your native code for one or more specific ABI(s) by adding an ABI filter:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    ... other stuff ...
}
```

Comment: this was it, thanks!